# Error in calculation of raster mean

Tags: raster, r, mean

I have a list of files corresponding to MODIS Aerosol Optical Depth (AOD). A part of list I would like to provide as sample is as follows
The sample list of files is:

```
MOD04_L2.A2020153.0445.061.2020153132053.pssggs_000501596310-Optical_Depth_Land_And_Ocean
MOD04_L2.A2020153.0450.061.2020153132030.pssggs_000501596310-Optical_Depth_Land_And_Ocean
MOD04_L2.A2020153.0625.061.2020153201214.pssggs_000501596310-Optical_Depth_Land_And_Ocean
MOD04_L2.A2020153.0630.061.2020153201029.pssggs_000501596310-Optical_Depth_Land_And_Ocean
MOD04_L2.A2020154.0355.061.2020154132511.pssggs_000501596310-Optical_Depth_Land_And_Ocean
```

From the list I would like to calculate sum of rasters with 2020153 as a part of its name.

As rasters of AOD are available at regular intervals in a day I would like to average AOD on day basis using R. The procedure is to be adopted for a period of 20 years for my analysis. I tried the following code to calculate the sum of AOD.

```
library(raster)
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
library(maptools)
library(mapdata)
library(maps)
library(stringr)
setwd("D:/lockdown/stack")
files <- list.files()
s1 <- raster(files[1])
NAvalue(s1) <- -9999
s1 <- setMinMax(s1)
p <- names(s1)
t <- str_sub(p,11,17)
for(i in 2:5){
  r <- raster(files[3])
  NAvalue(r) <- -9999
  r <- setMinMax(r)
  q <- names(r)
  g <- str_sub(q,11,17)
  if(g==t)
     s1 <- s1+r
}
```

**Unfortunately I am not able to execute the code. The final result I could obtain is a raster named s1 with all NA**

Comment: How closely have you looked at your code? It doesn't use `i` in the loop. It gets `files[3]` every time.

Answer (score 1):

You do not provide us with information on the format of your data (eg., tif, nc, bil) and you code does not track with the description of what you are after.

For the most part, raster/terra will parse the correct nodata value as NA. If you are using NetCDF data, add the `netcdf4` package into your R environment and the data will be parsed correctly. For formats such as tif the nodata values are automatically parsed into NA.

You can use `grep` to create an index, representing the name/text matching, and pass it directly to a raster stack.

Assuming a stack of rasters, where the sum represents the at-pixel values and results in a new raster.

```
f <- files(getwd(), "tif$")
  r <- stack(r)
    rsum <- calc(r[[grep("2020153", f)]], "sum")
```

Assuming that you just want the sum, of all pixels in rasters associated with a name query, for each raster.

```
f <- files(getwd(), "tif$")
  lapply(f, function(x) {
    s <- raster(f)
    sum(s[], na.rm=TRUE)
  })
```